# System reboots after some time automatically

Tags: windows-7, reboot

My PC restarts after some time automatically and then throw multiple errors as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

- CPU and RAM usages are negligible.

It is happening every time. The PC works fine for few minutes and then restarts. Once it tries to restart then, it throws this black screen with an error. If I switch off the power and restart it again then, it will work for another few minutes before automatic reboot with a black screen.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested in the comments, I ran the SMART diagnostic tool and the result look as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Are the attributes shown in Yellow critical that could lead to a system restart in a few minutes?

Comment: Looks like you have a failing hard drive, back up your critical data to an external drive and be prepared to install a new hard drive and reinstall of the operating system.

Comment: @Moab: But if there is a problem in HDD then how come the system works fine for few minutes before rebooting automatically?

Comment: Because computer component failures aren't binary. They have more states than completely working and completely failed.

Comment: You should run S.M.A.R.T. diagnostics to confirm.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong: Ok, I am reading about S.M.A.R.T and finding an app for it.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong: I ran a tool for  SMART and updated the results in my question.

Comment: I do not believe so. It does indicate that you should be looking to replace the drive in the future. I also does not appear to be overheating, which was my next guess. If we treat the missing boot device after restart as a red-herring, then I'm still thinking overheating. Likely the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I would at minimum suspect a hard disk cabling issue, if not imminent HD failure.

The PXE pre-boot environment is unlikely to be needed in a regular domestic machine & you should switch it off, though I'd deal with the failing HD first before bothering with the boot setup.

Those two errors are generated when a boot disk cannot be found **and** a network cable is not plugged in [that would happen if you used wifi]

See [Intel - PXE-E61 Media Test Failure Error for Intel® Desktop Boards](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005740/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html) for details.

Comment: But the PC works fine for few minutes (last time for 20 minutes) before rebooting and throwing this error.

Comment: Which is why I've included a cabling issue in my answer. An intermittent SATA cable will cause all kinds of random weirdness [up to & including total data loss] & yet look fine for minutes or hours at a time. If you have more than one drive, the failing cable doesn't even have to be the one to the boot drive either.